# Firebase RecyclerView not working properly, getting null values in released apk

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Firebase recyclerview is not showing desired results in released mode while it works properly in debug mode. It is giving null values in released mode but it displays correct value in the debug app mode.

Firebase is returning null values in recycler view.

Firebase Recyclerview Code:

```
//For setting time
    /*CarouselModel carouselModel = new CarouselModel("Tomorrow's QuizPoint at 10:00 PM","₹50,000","1562587387000","1562587389000");
    quizTiming.push().setValue(carouselModel);*/

    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("quizTimings");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<CarouselModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<CarouselModel>()
                    .setQuery(query, CarouselModel.class)
                    .build();

    scrollView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.picker);

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<CarouselModel, TimeViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        public TimeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_time, viewGroup, false);

            return new TimeViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(TimeViewHolder timeViewHolder, int i, final CarouselModel carouselModel) {

            try {
                if (carouselModel.getTime()!=null && !carouselModel.getTime().isEmpty()){
                    String quizTimings = carouselModel.getTime();
                    timeViewHolder.timeShow.setText(quizTimings);
                }else {
                    timeViewHolder.timeShow.setText("error Time");
                }

                if (carouselModel.getTimeMoney()!=null && !carouselModel.getTimeMoney().isEmpty()){
                    String timeMoney = carouselModel.getTimeMoney();
                    timeViewHolder.timeMoney.setText(timeMoney);
                }else {
                    timeViewHolder.timeMoney.setText("error TimeMoney");
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                String err = (ex.getMessage()==null)?"QuizTiming error":ex.getMessage();
                Log.e("quiztiming logs","error "+err);
            }
        }
    };

    CustomLinearLayout linearLayoutManager = new CustomLinearLayout(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);

    scrollView.addItemDecoration(new LinePagerIndicatorDecoration(MainActivity.this));
    scrollView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    scrollView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image: debug version]

[image: released apk]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your pojo class is public and add

```
@Keep
```

to the pojo classes that you use to retrieve and display firebase data if you are using

```
minifyEnabled true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It fixed the issue. I had to add keep statements in proguard file, and now recyclerview is working properly in released version as well.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to update latest SHA1 Key from Playstore console

Playstore console --> Release Management -->  App signing --> App Signing Certificate (Top) --> SHA1 copy 
and paste at Your Firebase --> Project Settings--> add fingerprint

2. Now Download Latest google-service.json file and replace file in your android studio.
3. If  minifyEnabled true (build.gradle(app)) you have to wrire progurd rules in proguard-rules.pro

Comment: Yes, I had already done that. Those are not the issues. I'm getting data from firebase and using it  in from other nodes. It's just recyclerview that is not working.

Comment: what about this  --> If minifyEnabled true (build.gradle(app)) you have to wrire progurd rules in proguard-rules.pro